how to store custom field inside session in next-auth authjs v5 nextjs 14
i have something like this inside my auth.config.ts

declare module "next-auth" {
  interface Session {
    isVerified: boolean;
  }
}

export default {
  providers: [
    Credentials({
      credentials: {
        phone: {},
        password: {},
      },
      authorize: async (credentials) => {
        const user = await axios.post("/signin", {
          phone: credentials.phone,
          password: credentials.password,
        });

        if (!user) return null;

        return user.data;
      },
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user }) {
      token.isVerified = false;
      return { ...token, ...user };
    },

    async session({ session, token }) {
      session.user = token as any;
      session.isVerified = token.isVerified as boolean;
      return session;
    },
  },
} satisfies NextAuthConfig;

what i want is that after user logs in i want the user redirects to the otp page then when otp is success i want to store isVerified custom field inside my session then route the user to the dashboard page
this is what my otp server action looks like
const otp = async (values: z.infer\<typeof OTPSchema\>) =\> {
const { otp } = values;
const session = await auth();

try {
  const res = await verifyOtp(otp);
    if (res.data) {
      if (session) {
        session.isVerified = true;
      }
    
           return { success: "OTP Success" };
         }

       }  catch (error) {
          if (error instanceof AxiosError) {
          console.log(error.response);
    }
    return { error: "Invalid otp" };
  }
};

after i set the session.isVerified to true its getting reset back to loggin
this is what my middleware looks like
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
import createIntlMiddleware from "next-intl/middleware";
import { auth } from "@/auth";
import {
  apiAuthPrefix,
  authRoutes,
  DEFAULT_LOGIN_REDIRECT,
  isOtpRoute,
  publicRoutes,
} from "./routes";
import next from "next";

const locales = ["en", "am"];
const publicPages = ["/", "/auth/login", "/auth/register"];

const intlMiddleware = createIntlMiddleware({
  locales,
  defaultLocale: "en",
});

const authMiddleware = auth((req) => {
  const { nextUrl } = req;
  const isLoggedIn = !!req.auth;
  const isApiAuthRoute = nextUrl.pathname.startsWith(apiAuthPrefix);
  const isPublicRoute = publicRoutes.includes(nextUrl.pathname);
  const isAuthRoute = authRoutes.includes(nextUrl.pathname);
  const isOtpPage = nextUrl.pathname.includes("/auth/otp");
  // If the user is logged in but not verified, only allow them to access the OTP page

  console.log({ isLogged: req.auth?.isVerified });

  if (isLoggedIn && !req.auth?.isVerified) {
    if (isOtpPage) {
      return intlMiddleware(req);
    } else {
      return Response.redirect(new URL("/auth/otp", nextUrl));
    }
  }
  if (isOtpPage) {
    if (isLoggedIn) {
      return Response.redirect(new URL("/dashboard", nextUrl));
    }
  }

  if (isLoggedIn) {
    return intlMiddleware(req);
  }
});

export default function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
  const publicPathnameRegex = RegExp(
    `^(/(${locales.join("|")}))?(${publicPages
      .flatMap((p) => (p === "/" ? ["", "/"] : p))
      .join("|")})/?$`,
    "i"
  );

  const isPublicPage = publicPathnameRegex.test(req.nextUrl.pathname);

  if (isPublicPage) {
    return intlMiddleware(req);
  } else {
    return (authMiddleware as any)(req);
  }
}

export const config = {
  matcher: ["/((?!.+\\.[\\w]+$|_next).*)", "/", "/(api|trpc)(.*)"],
};

